# PHP/Wordpress How to get key/index value from array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array of values where I want the index/key value for each item, so that I can use that value to apply it as a class for styling purposes. How can I achieve that?

Here is what I got so far:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('case'),
  'post_status' => array('publish'),
  'posts_per_page' => 5
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts() ){
        $query->the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="grid-item item--HERE I WANT THE KEY/INDEX VALUE">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
           <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php }
}
```

I want the output to be something like this:

```
<div class="grid-item item--1"> 
  ...etc etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

`<?php 
echo $query->current_post +1;
?>`

More at: [Wordpress Class Reference - Wp Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you actually want, you can do this one of several ways. To use an incremental value:

```
<div class="grid-item item--<?php echo esc_attr( $query->current_post + 1 ); ">
```

Or use the post ID:

```
<div class="grid-item item--<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ">
```

Or use the post slug:

```
<div class="grid-item item--<?php echo esc_attr( $post->post_name ); ">
```

Note that I use `esc_attr()` to sanitize the output, which is considered a best practice for security, and would be required if you were to be publishing to WordPress VIP, for example.